# PHP SOAP WSDL - Could not connect to host

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

there is a problem trying to execute some functions from the WSDL I have. I connected to the WSDL using Basic Auth, I can see all the functions available with:`$functions = $client->__getFunctions();`

But then I try to execute any of them I get "[HTTP] Could not connect to host" error. My code here:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 150);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$opts = array(
'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)
);

// SOAP 1.2 client
$params = array (
'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
'verifypeer' => false,
'verifyhost' => false,
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1,
"connection_timeout" => 180,
'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
'login' => 'login',
'password' => 'password',
'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);
$url = "http://address/webservice/wsdl";

try {
$client = new SoapClient($url, $params);
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
var_dump($functions);


$response = $client->__soapCall('function_name', array());
$client->function_name();

var_dump($response);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
echo '<br>'.$fault;
}
```

Any ideas? Now in the WSDL file I have a targetNamespace parameter which is "targetNamespace="http://192.168.0.253:85/webservice/soap"" can this be a legit WSDL file? I mean can the namespace be a localhost ip address? Maybe this needs to be fixed in the WSDL side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. What was missing:

```
    'location' => "http://address/webservice/soap",
```

In parameters.